# Combine PHP variable with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, variables

Im working on my admin panel and I'm facing a problem. I'm using a small script which outputs my server CPU usage and I want to integrate that into a javascript chart. I cant get it working..
And I want to know how to make the variable work in the javascript chart.

My PHP:

```
<?php

$stat1 = file('/proc/stat'); 
sleep(1); 
$stat2 = file('/proc/stat'); 
$info1 = explode(" ", preg_replace("!cpu +!", "", $stat1[0])); 
$info2 = explode(" ", preg_replace("!cpu +!", "", $stat2[0])); 
$dif = array(); 
$dif['user'] = $info2[0] - $info1[0]; 
$dif['nice'] = $info2[1] - $info1[1]; 
$dif['sys'] = $info2[2] - $info1[2]; 
$dif['idle'] = $info2[3] - $info1[3]; 
$total = array_sum($dif); 
$cpu = array(); 
foreach($dif as $x=>$y) $cpu[$x] = round($y / $total * 100, 1);
$usedcpu = $cpu['user'] + $cpu['nice'] + $cpu['sys'];

?>
```

And my javascript

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Demo #1
        // we use an inline data source in the example, usually data would be fetched from a server
        var data = "<?php echo $usedcpu; ?>";
        function getData() {
            return data;
        }

        // setup control widget
        var updateInterval = 30;
        $("#updateInterval").val(updateInterval).change(function () {
            var v = $(this).val();
            if (v && !isNaN(+v)) {
                updateInterval = +v;
            if (updateInterval < 1)
                updateInterval = 1;
            if (updateInterval > 2000)
                updateInterval = 2000;
            $(this).val("" + updateInterval);
            }
        });

        // setup plot
        var options = {
            series: {
                shadowSize: 0,
                color: '#c0382b',
                lines: {
                    fill: true
                }
            }, // drawing is faster without shadows
            yaxis: { min: 0, max: 10 },
            xaxis: { show: false },
            grid: { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', borderColor: 'transparent' },
        };
        var plot = $.plot($("#demo-1"), [ getData() ], options);

        function update() {
            plot.setData([ getData() ]);
            // since the axes don't change, we don't need to call plot.setupGrid()
            plot.draw();
            setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
        }

        update();

    });
</script>
```

I hope you guys can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry if thats not clear, I want to make the variabe $usedcpu work in the chart

Comment: `And my jQuery` if you include `jquery.js` in your page, your javascript doesn't become _jquery_ and it should be referred as javascript.

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't use this site often!

Comment: @wouterdz: I still have no idea what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: You see the $usedcpu variable, it outputs a variable like 2.1 (example), I want to have that number used in the plot(javascript). Im trying to make a var and echo the $usedcpu in there but that doesn't work...

Comment: Is the PHP code BEFORE the jQuery code in the file? (Is it the same file)

Comment: Yes it is! And echo $usedcpu just outputs a value..

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP to write JS but not the other way around. PHP is server-side, JS is client-side.

You COULD use a .php file as a 'javascript file' by having PHP build the javascript.

Of course you would have to wrap it in a `<script>` block and include it via php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Stuff
<?php 
  $someVar = 'some string';
  echo "var jsVariable = '{$someVar}';";
?>
//more stuff
</script>
```

Though that's pretty convoluted and can get messy fast. Why not use PHP to create JSON and interpret with JS?

Comment: I made a variable called data in Javascript and I guess I did it like you told me but if I want to add it in the plot (javascript) it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend placing your values from php into a hidden html field with unique id. Then in your javascript you can grab that value. Just one way of doing it.

Comment: But the way im doing it now isn't correct? Just placing the PHP variable into a js one?

Comment: Well I have never done it the way your doing it so I cannot say for sure. But it is always best to separate your javascript and php code into separate files. That would be best practice and easier for you to reuse code and fix any issues that may come up

Answer (score 1):

Since `$usedcpu` is a number that you want to use in the plot you don't want the quotes in the javascript var.  The following will make a javascript variable called `usedcpu` that you can use in the plot code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <php?
        echo "var usedcpu = " . $usedcpu . ";"
    ?>
</script>
```